# How to start new k8s pod from LOCAL docker image?

Tags: docker, minikube

I am learning docker and k8s. Now I have following local docker images on MAC Mojave:
[image]

Please note I cannot connect "gcr.io" for some reason, so I created a docker file within gitHub:
**FROM gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0**

Then I leverage "hub.docker.com" to create automated build based on that gitHub docker file:
[image]

Then I run **docker pull** and **docker tag**, so that's why there is a gcr.io image after docker images.
I installed minikube version: 0.25.0, and create a pod with yaml(kubectl). Run **kubectl get pods**, the pod status stuck with "ContainerCreating". Then run **minikube logs**, it shows **failed pulling image "gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0**:
[image]

I am confused here:
I already have local image for **gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64**, why k8s still try to connect gcr.io other than local one? How to have k8s grab that image from local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Finally, I resolve this issue:

- Run **"minikube ssh"**
- docker login docker hub
- docker pull pause-amd64:3.0 in docker hub
- docker tag to "gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0"

Now the pod status is "Running":) 
So the reason is minikube leverages the docker on the node other than host's docker...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is related to imagePullPolicy, try to specify imagePullPolicy:Never otherwise local images will not be used. Also, you can have a look at this [tutorial](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/0c616a6b42b28a1aab8397f5a9061f8ebbd9f3d9/README.md#reusing-the-docker-daemon)